# Blank first UITableView section header

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have 2 sections in my UITableView. I'd like my first header to be nonexistant, no space, no nothing. The first cell touches the top of the screen. I'd like a custom section header for my second section.

I can do this if I don't use `- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` but the moment I use this method a blank header view appears in the first section. What am I doing wrong?

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (!section == 0){
        UIView *header = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 30.0f)];
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:[header frame]];
        [label setText:@"Test Header"];
        [header addSubview:label];

        return header;
    }
    else{
        // This apparently causes a header to appear in section 0. 
        // Without this entire method it works fine- but it means I can't customize
        // the header.
        return nil;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look for the

`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`

method of `UITableView`.

You can `return 0;` for the first section.

Answer (score 1):

Use this,

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0){       
        return 0;
    }
    //...
}
```